# Proper use of WAI-ARIA states?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

When applying ARIA states dynamically, what is the best option? I'm only asking as it's not always easy to decipher the proper use from the spec's alone.

- Should you apply `false` as a state when able? By this I mean, is there a difference between explicitly saying `false` or not having the attribute present, if so, what?
- Should these attributes be present in the initial load of the DOM or only toggled when interacted with? I'm referring primarily to `aria-states`, not `aria-properties` or `aria-roles` as they're less likely to change.

**Example 1**

```
<div role="tablist">
  <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
</div>
```

vs. (note: the `aria-selected` is *not* present when `false`)

```
<div role="tablist">
  <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="panel-2">Tab 2</a>
</div>
```

---

**Example 2**

```
<div>
  <div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false"></div>
  <div id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

vs. (note: the attribute has been removed again, `aria-hidden` is *not* present when `false`)

```
<div>
  <div id="panel-1" role="tabpanel"></div>
  <div id="panel-2" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

*should `aria-hidden` be used at all since it will be visible at some point?*

---

*I'm using `style=display:none` as an example, you would probably want to use either an `.active` and/or `.visuallyhidden` class instead.*

Comment: It seems that you have three questions that are not closely related: 1. `false` value (which [I tried to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29511969/1591669)), 2. initial load of the DOM, 3. usage of `aria-hidden`. I think it would make sense to create separate questions for the two additional questions (and [edit] them out here). Do you agree?

Comment: yes, now that you mention the value differences this does seem to be separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on its [value type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/states_and_properties#propcharacteristic_value_header):

- [`aria-selected`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/states_and_properties#aria-selected) has the value type "true/false/undefined" where the default value is always *undefined*, which means in this case:

  > The element is not selectable.

  This is different to the value *false*, which means in this case:

  > The selectable element is not selected.

  → So you should specify `aria-selected` if its value shall be *false*.
- [`aria-hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) has the value type "true/false" where the default value is always *false*.

  → So you don’t have to specify `aria-hidden` if its value shall be *false*.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think to check for differing values. That clears up a lot, thanks!